# How to add image on customer/account/login/ page in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm using theme default customer log in page. 
Which basically looks like this
[image]

So I'm wondering is that possible I could add a image on the left column, under those texts (By creating an account ******in your account and more.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Don't edit core file copy your theme and edit `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml`

Create static block and add your image then call above mention phtml where ever you want